How do I add the current Week number in Looker Studio on screen
I think what I probably need is a calculated field with something like this in the formula:
WEEK(CURRENT_DATE())

But I can't figure out how to include that in somekind of Scorecard or some other visual element where I can display a TEXT (String) bound to live data like the current datetime on my Looker Studio page.

Simple

Add a score card to the page
Add date as a metric to the scorecard
Click on the edit button on the date metric in the score card
Change the datatype to ISO week
Change the aggregation to Max

This will provide you with a week number for the latest week in the data

The aggregation is what tripped me up. Could you explain why MAX makes sense here? I don't understand why my calculated field is being treated as somekind of array of values instead of a single value returned by WEEK(CURRENT_DATE())

Looker studio is a visualization tool, its not very good at doing calculations, The max finds the highest number or most recent date, you could use WEEK(Date as Text, CURRENT_DATE()) to get your formula to work but the you might end up with problems around UTC vs your data sources time and a slow down in performance
